# Why does repeat function not work the second time?

Tags: javascript, arrays

The challenge is to return an array that follows an arrow pattern when given a number. For example:

```
arrow(3) ➞ [">", ">>", ">>>", ">>", ">"]
```

I have almost completed it but it repeats the middle value in the array twice.

```js
function arrow(n) {
    var arr = [];
    var num = 1;
    while(num <= n) {
    arr.push(">".repeat(num));
        num++;
    }
    while(num > 0) {
        arr.push(">".repeat(num - 1));
        num--;
    }
    return arr;
}
console.log(arrow(3));
```

So then I changed it to this (for the second repeat I changed it to `num - 2` but it says an error).

```js
function arrow(n) {
    var arr = [];
    var num = 1;
    while(num <= n) {
    arr.push(">".repeat(num));
        num++;
    }
    while(num > 0) {
        arr.push(">".repeat(num - 2));
        num--;
    }
    return arr;
}
console.log(arrow(3));
```

Can someone explain to me why this doesn't work?

Comment: *"but it says an error."* What error?

Comment: Going to edit the question for clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function does not work because you start the second loop when `num` is equal to `n + 1` (which causes the middle value to be added twice) and do not end the loop until `num` is `0` (which causes an empty string to be appended to the result). For a simpler solution, you can use `Array.from` with a bit of arithmetic.

```js
function arrow(n) {
    return Array.from({length: n * 2 - 1}, (_,i)=>">".repeat(i < n ? i + 1 : n * 2 - 1 - i));
}
console.log(arrow(3));
```

Answer (score 1):

The error with the first solution is that when `num` equals `3`, you increment it to `4` in the `while` loop. When the second `while` loop runs, `num - 1`then equals 3.

In the second solution, `num - 2` will equal `-1` during the fourth iteration, which throws an error.

A for-loop may be easier to control here:

```
function arrow(n) {
    var arr = [];
    var num = 1;
    for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      arr.push(">".repeat(i))
    }
    for (let i = n - 1; i > 0; i--) {
      arr.push(">".repeat(i));
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Comment: Complement with the solution: keep `num - 1`, but put `num--` between the two `while`s

Answer (score 1):

The first one does not work because "num" is incremented a last time and thus equals "n + 1" when the code goes out from the while loop.
So if "n" = 3, when the code executes the first "while(num > 0) {", num will equal 4. So 4 - 1 = 3 repetition of the arrow.

So, to fix it :

```
function arrow(n) {
    var arr = [];
    var num = 1;
    while(num <= n) {
        arr.push(">".repeat(num));
        num++;
    }
    num--; // add this line
    while(num > 0) {
        arr.push(">".repeat(num - 1));
        num--;
    }
    return arr;
}
console.log(arrow(3));
```

Comment: I also forgot to mention that there's an extra value at the end. Do you know why that's there?

Comment: The last iteration will leave "num" equal to 1. So you push ">".repeat(0) to the array - an empty string.
Is this what are you talking about ?

Answer (score 0):

**The issue with your second function :**

when you were using the second while loop, the value of num was decreasing by 1 in each loop.
when the loop value of num comes to 1 , and and you tried to use   `arr.push(">".repeat(num - 2));` , then **n-2 = -1** , but **repeat(-1)** is invalid function.

---

**Solution:**

I think in between two while loop, use **num--**; to decrease the value of num by 1. it will solve your problem.

```js
function arrow(n) {
    var arr = [];
    var num = 1;
    while(num <= n) {
    arr.push(">".repeat(num));
        num++;
    }
    num --;
    while(num > 1) {
        arr.push(">".repeat(num - 1));
        num--;
    }
    return arr;
}
console.log(arrow(3));
```

Comment: There's also an extra value at the end? How to fix that?

Comment: thanks for pointing out the error. I solved the issue, check the snippet . in the second while loop, I use while(num > 1)  instead of while(num > 0). if you like the solution give an upvote, thanks

Answer (score 0):

so when your loop get the last element number == 1
the repeat function (num-2) will not work
for this challenger i simply put a (number--;) in the middle of the While loops
i hope that work.

```
function arrow(n) {
    var arr = [];
    var num = 1;
    while(num <= n) {
    arr.push(">".repeat(num));
        num++;
    }
    num--; // take 1 out
    while(num > 1) {
        arr.push(">".repeat(num -1));

        num--;
    }
    return arr;
}

console.log(arrow(3));
```